# How do you get NoData to show up transparent in a .TIF file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, nodata

I am creating a handful of raster images using ArcGIS 10. I've been exporting the rasters as .TIF files. From what I've read, even though you can set the background to No Color, this actually doesn't do anything since .TIF files do not support transparency. My background ends up gray in color for NoData areas when I select this option.

I have tried setting the .TIF file's properties to display NoData as 255,255,255 and that didn't work either. I also tried reclassifying the data and setting the NoData color to transparent and that failed as well. I even tried using QGIS and selecting the pixel for NoData and changed that to 100% transparent and that didn't work either.

My goal is to get the .TIF loaded into TileMill, then export the .TIF to MapBox Tiles and display the image using MapBox's Online Editor. I have done this successfully in the past exporting the image from data view in ArcGIS, but for whatever reason can't seem to get it to work today. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: When you click (identify) on grey area, what are the numbers?